# Project references in tsconfig and ambient declarations

Tags: typescript, build, dependencies, tsconfig

I am trying to configure my Typescript project to have the following directory structure:

```
src/
├── client/
│   └── tsconfig.json
│
├── server/
│   └── tsconfig.json
│
├── shared/
│   ├── utils/
│   │   └── type-utils.d.ts
│   │
│   └── tsconfig.json
│
└── tsconfig-base.json
```

- `client/tsconfig.json`, `server/tsconfig.json`, and `shared/tsconfig.json` each have `"extends": "../tsconfig-base.json"`
- `client/tsconfig.json` and `server/tsconfig.json` both have `"references": [{ "path": "../shared" }]`
- `shared/utils/type-utils.d.ts` is not a module, but instead contains ambient type declarations like `Id` and `CouldBeNull`, as well as a declaration merge for `Array` (defining the `flatMap` method).

The idea being that `tsconfig-base.json` could include a lot of common settings, the individual `tsconfig.json`s could define settings relevant for that sub-project (e.g. React for `client/tsconfig.json`, Node for `server/tsconfig.json`), and `shared/` would be shared between `client/` and `server/`.

The problem is that the ambient declarations and declaration mergin `shared/utils/type-utils.ts` is not seen by `client/` or `server/`, but only by `shared/`. This causes errors, for example `tsc -b client --verbose` produces

```
$ tsc -b client --verbose
15:31:41 - Projects in this build:
    * shared/tsconfig.json
    * client/tsconfig.json

15:31:41 - Project 'shared/tsconfig.json' is up to date because newest input 'shared/formatting/numbers.ts' is older than oldest output 'shared/formatting/numbers.js.map'

15:31:41 - Project 'client/tsconfig.json' is out of date because output file 'client/client/index.js' does not exist

15:31:41 - Building project 'C:/Users/KRyan/Web/5heet/client/tsconfig.json'...

client/index.tsx(32,29): error TS7006: Parameter 'skill' implicitly has an 'any' type.
client/index.tsx(80,37): error TS2339: Property 'flatMap' does not exist on type 'Ability[]'.
client/index.tsx(80,45): error TS7006: Parameter 'ability' implicitly has an 'any' type.
client/index.tsx(88,16): error TS7006: Parameter 'one' implicitly has an 'any' type.
client/index.tsx(88,21): error TS7006: Parameter 'another' implicitly has an 'any' type.
client/index.tsx(151,32): error TS7031: Binding element 'id' implicitly has an 'any' type.
client/parts/editing.tsx(31,60): error TS2339: Property 'oneOperand' does not exist on type 'never'.
client/parts/editing.tsx(31,81): error TS2339: Property 'operator' does not exist on type 'never'.
client/parts/editing.tsx(31,108): error TS2339: Property 'anotherOperand' does not exist on type 'never'.
client/parts/portal.tsx(55,61): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Omit'.
shared/ability.d.ts(2,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Id'.
shared/ability.d.ts(8,36): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Id'.
shared/ability.d.ts(12,37): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Id'.
shared/character.d.ts(3,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Id'.
shared/expression.d.ts(7,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Id'.
shared/expression.d.ts(30,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ElementOf'.
shared/expression.d.ts(33,118): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Id'.
shared/formatting/numbers.d.ts(1,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Id'.
shared/skill.d.ts(3,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Id'.
shared/utils/basic.d.ts(5,46): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CouldBeNull'.
```

The implicit `any` types are caused directly by the inability to find the various names listed in the second half of the output.

And, for completeness’s sake, the full files:

`shared/utils/type-utils.d.ts`:

```
type PropsOf<T> = T[keyof T];
type ElementOf<T> = T extends (infer E)[] ? E : T;
type Subtract<T, U> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>>;
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
type CouldBeNull<T> = null extends T ? unknown : never;

type DeepPartial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P] extends Array<infer U>
    ? Array<DeepPartial<U>>
    : T[P] extends ReadonlyArray<infer U>
    ? ReadonlyArray<DeepPartial<U>>
    : DeepPartial<T[P]>
};

declare class Tagged<Tag> {
    private 'is tagged as': [Tag];
    private dummy(): Tag;
}
type Id<Tag> = string & Tagged<Tag>;

interface Array<T> {
    /**
     * Calls a defined callback function on each element of an array. Then, flattens the result into
     * a new array.
     * This is identical to a map followed by a flatten of depth 1.
     *
     * @param callback A function that accepts up to three arguments. The flatMap method calls the
     * callback function one time for each element in the array.
     * @param thisArg An object to which the this keyword can refer in the callback function. If
     * thisArg is omitted, undefined is used as the this value.
     */
    flatMap<U, This = undefined>(
        callback: (this: This, value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U | U[],
        thisArg?: This,
    ): U[];
}
```

`tsconfig-base.json`:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2018",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "module": "amd",
        "moduleResolution": "classic",
        "paths": {
            "csstype": [
                "node_modules/csstype/index"
            ],
        },
        "composite": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "allowJs": false,
        "allowUnusedLabels": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noStrictGenericChecks": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noErrorTruncation": true,
        "allowUnreachableCode": false,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

`client/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig-base.json",
    "include": [
        "**/*.ts"
    ],
    "outDir": "../../built/client",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": "..",
        "jsx": "react",
        "types": [
            "react",
            "react-dom"
        ]
    },
    "references": [
        {
            "path": "../shared"
        }
    ],
    "watch": true
}
```

`server/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig-base.json",
    "include": [
        "**/*.ts"
    ],
    "outDir": "../../built/server",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": "..",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "types": [
            "node",
            "mime-types"
        ]
    },
    "references": [
        {
            "path": "../shared"
        }
    ]
}
```

`shared/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig-base.json",
    "include": [
        "**/*.ts"
    ],
    "outDir": "built/shared",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "amd",
        "types": []
    }
}
```

Comment: @E_net4 is kind and welcoming Why is the four-space indent preferable to `<pre>` tags? Just trying to understand the system, I’d never noticed a difference before.

Comment: `<pre>` tags do not provide syntax highlighting, unlike four-space indentation. It is also a more natural (Markdown) way of formatting code.

Answer (score 6):

Figured out *a* solution, though I’m not wild about it:

`client/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig-base.json",
    "include": [
        "**/*.ts",
        "**/*.tsx",
        "../shared/utils/type-utils.d.ts"
    ],
    "outDir": "../built/client",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "..",
        "rootDir": "..",
        "jsx": "react",
        "types": [
            "react",
            "react-dom"
        ]
    },
    "references": [
        {
            "path": "../shared"
        }
    ],
    "watch": true
}
```

Note the `../shared/utils/type-utils.d.ts` in the `include` section. This solves the problem.

I’m not wild about this solution because it means explicitly listing something in `shared/` rather than it just being included as a result of the project reference. I am not happy about the thought that I would have to manually update my `tsconfig.json`s for each new `.d.ts` file I want to add `shared/`. But this is *an* answer, in that the project builds, and I’m not overly *likely* to add more of my own `.d.ts` files to the project, so my concerns are possibly philosophical/theoretical for this project.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. Helped a lot. It's pretty old but if it's still of some use you can replace "../shared/utils/type-utils.d.ts" with "../**/*.d.ts" which is somewhat better, worked for me.

Comment: @AlonBar I honestly can’t remember whether or not I actually tried that, but if I didn’t that would have been pretty dumb of me—seems like a pretty obvious thing to try. But I’m glad there’s a better solution here.